# npm task before launch debug

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, sharepoint-online, npm-scripts

I am working with SharePoint online client side customization.

The worst part of the work is to open IE, open with explorer, go to vs code, open folder. And many times the connection is dropped, then I have to repeat the same.

This is required given the limitations we have to the resources within the SP site.

I was able to map the remote code with my local files with the vs code, so I can debug it within the editor without the need to open the remote folder locally.

What I was wondering now is: is it possible to create a npm preLaunchTask script to upload my files to the SharePoint folder?

The problems I have to figure out are:

1- I would need to track the file I just changed or the changes I have made to the source dir before actually uploading anything.

2- I can't use the digest value from the page since there will be no page to take it from before vs code launches the browser. Any way I can authenticate and grab a valid digest token as result?

3- I would need to get the file to upload content within the java script since there will be no html input available. Is it possible? How?

So these are my problems I would upload the files using the rest api. Any other ideas of how I can get arround this is also very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did make some progress and here is what I could come up so far.

2 and 3. I created a puppeteer script which logs me in, saves the session and uploads the files I pass to the script.

Now I just need to figure out how to run a task when a file is changed or to monitor the dir.

Thanks.